# Yii complex authorization

Tags: php, yii, authorization, rbac

I'm working with YII framework.

Let's say we have:

- VideoController
- PhotoController
- ContentController
- CategoryController

What I need is to create user access control system based on controller group privileges. I mean, lets say, user named john who is super admin, can access all controllers, while user named jessy who is writer role user can access only content controller.

I googled a lot. And found some blogposts about RBAC which very complex to understand. Is there any good blogpost about this? any suggestions?

Comment: Do develop some tricks from http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac/ . If it doesn't help you, let me know to help you .

Answer (score 0):

First, IMHO RBAC simplifies your life. Its not complicated to understand or implement.

As far as implementation goes, I recommend managing your RBAC tree with ready made extensions, even if they're not bug free (they do get the job done - which is managing the tree. They have UI issues, at least im my taste). Checkout RBAM and SRBAC.

Now for your main event, I would have organized your permission's tree as follows:

```
admin (role)
^
|
-- Content Editor (role)  <----------------
|    ^                                     |
|    |                                     |
|    -- Create content (task)              |
|    -- Update content (task)              -< Authenticated user (role) <--- Guest user (role)
|    -- Delete content (task)              |                                  ^
|    -- and so on...                       |                                  |
|                                          |                                  -- view content (task)                                         |
-- Category Editor (role) <----------------                                   -- login (task)
    ^
    |
    -- Create category (task)
    -- and so on...
```

The sample RBAC tree above demonstrates *roles* which are as you might imagine, and those can inherit from other roles, just as you'd expect in a tree structure and 'include' tasks. 
This is just one way to organize your permissions/authorization tree. TIMTOWTDI... .
I've also skipped detailing meaningful tasks on 'authenticated user' role but of course there could be such.

Check out also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357550/what-exactly-are-tasks-in-yiis-rbac).